# C# WindowsForms NumericUpDown "cannot equal x value" property?

Tags: c#, winforms, properties, numericupdown

Due to my application being a quadratic root solver, and receiving input from a NumericUpDown in the form of `0` will throw a `divide by zero` error, I was wondering if it was possible to be able to specify that particular NumericUpDown control, not able to be set to `0` at all.  Or, is it just easier to catch that with a conditional and resolve it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create a check in the Validating-event

```
private void numericUpDown1_Validating(object sender, CancelEventArgs e)
{
    if ((sender as NumericUpDown).Value == 0)
    {
        e.Cancel = true;
    }
}
```

But you also need the check in your code, always validate input...

Answer (score 0):

NumericUpDown has two properties calld [Minimum](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.numericupdown.minimum.aspx) and Maximum which set the min and max value for your up/down control. 
You can just set its Minimum to 1 so the user won't be able to select 0.

Comment: Yes, but I also need to account for the fact that I _can_ calculate negative values, just not zero.

Comment: mm in that case i think the only solution will be to handle the 0 when the NumericUpDown value change or in your function